# How to measure smoothness of a signal

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, smoothing, measurement, derivative

Lets say I have two signals with a different number of data points - a step function and a smooth spline as you can see below. What is mathematical operation I can use to quantify the "smoothness" of both signals.
Thanks.

[image: Curve1: a step function]

[[image: Curve2: a smooth spline2]

Comment: Maybe the sum of the second derivatives of the signal is worth an attempt.

Comment: I'm sure we can come up with *some* approach, but how would we know that it's sensible *for your purpose*? What do you need that smoothness measure for? If you can define that, we might even find an *optimal* measure – otherwise all we could do is *guess*.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a continuous function is smooth if it is infinitely differentiable. For a set of points, this definition is useless, and the "smoothness measure" completely depends on how you define "smoothness" as Marcus said. Math.SE is a better place for this kind of question. For example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349398/measure-of-curve-smoothness